# Characterising a set of outcomes containing the collection of pure strategy Nash equilibria

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Consider a game with $N$ players, each indexed by $i=1,...,N$. Every player $i$ has to choose a $J\times 1$ **vector** of actions $a_i\equiv (a_{i,1},...,a_{i,J})$ where each $a_{i,j}$ can be **zero or one**. The payoff of each player $i$ is $u_i(a_i, a_{-i})$, where $a_{-i}$ denotes the actions of the other players.

A pure strategy Nash equilibrium (PSNE) of the game is $a^*\equiv (a_1^*,...,a_N^*)$ solving
$$
(1) \quad a_i^*\in argmax_{a_i\in \{0,1\}^J} u_i(a_i, a^*_{-i}) \quad \forall i=1,...,N
$$

Note that if $a^*$ is a PSNE, then
$$
(2) \quad \text{If $a^*_{i,j}$=0, then } u_i(a^*_i, a^*_{-i})\geq u_i(a^*_i+\{a_{i,j}=1\}, a^*_{-i})\\
 \quad \quad \text{If $a^*_{i,j}$=1, then } u_i(a^*_i, a^*_{-i})\geq u_i(a^*_i+\{a_{i,j}=0\}, a^*_{-i})\\
\forall i=1,...,N \quad \forall j=1,...,J
$$
where $a^*_i+\{a_{i,j}=1\}$ denotes $a^*$ where $a^*_{i,j}=0$ is replaced by one; $a^*_i+\{a_{i,j}=0\}$ denotes $a^*$ where $a^*_{i,j}=1$ is replaced by zero.

**Claim:** Assume that ties are zero probability events. Then, an action profile $a$ satisfies (2) if and only if
$$
(3) \quad a_{i,j}=1\{u_i(a_i+\{a_{i,j}=1\}, a_{-i})- u_i(a_i+\{a_{i,j}=0\}, a_{-i})\geq 0\}\\
\forall i=1,...,N \quad \forall j=1,...,J
$$

**Question:** Let $A$ be the set of PSNE. Let $B$ be the set of $a$ satisfying (3). Is $A\subseteq B$? If $B$ is empty, then $A$ is empty?

Comment: The last $N$ should be a $J$, right?

Comment: I edited this (and a missing bracket).

Comment: @user3285148 For you question, are you also assuming that ties never occur?

Comment: Yes, ties never occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Condition 3 can be written in the following way: $a^\ast \in B$ iff for all $i$ and all $j$
$$
a^\ast_{i,j} = 1 \iff u_i(a_i^\ast + \{a_{i,j} = 1\}, a^\ast_{-i}) \ge u_i(a_i^\ast + \{a_{i,j} = 0\}, a^\ast_{-i})
$$
As there are no ties, this can be written as:
$$
a^\ast_{i,j} = 1 \to u_i(a_i^\ast + \{a_{i,j} = 1\}, a^\ast_{-i}) \ge u_i(a_i^\ast + \{a_{i,j} = 0\}, a^\ast_{-i}),\\
a^\ast_{i,j} = 0 \to u_i(a_i^\ast + \{a_{i,j} = 0\}, a^\ast_{-i}) \ge u_i(a_i^\ast + \{a_{i,j} = 1\}, a^\ast_{-i})
$$

If $a^\ast$ is a Nash equilibrium (i.e. $\in A$), then  for all $i$ and all $a_i$:
$$
u_i(a_i^\ast, a_{-i}^\ast) \ge u_i(a_i, a_{-i}^\ast)
$$

> Is $A \subseteq B$?

Yes. Let $a^\ast \in A$. We want to show that $a^\ast \in B$. To show that $a^\ast \in B$, we only need to look at deviations where $a_{i,j}^\ast$ changes for a particular $j$. Towards this end, define $a_i = (a_{i,\ell}|\ell \le J)$ such that:
$$
a_{i,\ell} = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} a^\ast_{i,l} &\text{ if } \ell \ne j\\ 1- a_{i,j}^\ast &\text{ if } \ell = j \end{array}\right.
$$
So $a_i$ differs from $a_i^\ast$ only because $a_{i,j}$ switched value (from 1 to 0 or vice versa). To show that $a^\ast \in B$, we show the two conditions.

1. If $a_{i,j}^\ast = 1$ , we have:

$$
u_i(a_i^\ast, a_{-i}^\ast) = u_i(a_i^\ast + \{a_{i,j} = 1\}, a_{-i}^\ast),\\
\ge u_i(a_i, a_{-i}^\ast) = u_i(a_i^\ast + \{a_{i,j} = 0\}, a_{-i}^\ast).
$$
The inequality follows from the definition of a Nash equilibrium. The equalities follow from how we defined $a_i$.

2. If $a^\ast_{i,j} = 0$, we have:

$$
u_i(a_i^\ast, a_{-i}^\ast) = u_i(a_i^\ast + \{a_{i,j} = 0\}, a_{-i}^\ast),\\
\ge u_i(a_i, a_{-i}^\ast) = u_i(a_i^\ast + \{a_{i,j} = 1\}, a_{-i}^\ast).
$$
This shows that $a^\ast \in B$.

> If $B$ is empty, then $A$ is empty?

This follows from $A \subseteq B$. If $B = \emptyset$ and $A$ is a subset of $B$ then immediately $A = \emptyset$.

Notice that the inclusion can be is strict, i.e. there are cases where $A \ne B$. To see this, consider the case where $J = 2$ and the payoff table is the following.

|  | (00) | (01) | (10) | (11) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **(00)** | 4,4 | 1,1 | 2,2 | 4,0 |
| **(01)** | 2,2 | 2,3 | 1,4 | 1,0 |
| **(10)** | 1,4 | 3,2 | 4,3 | 2,0 |
| **(11)** | 0,4 | 4,0 | 0,2 | 3,3 |

We have that $(11,11)$ is in $B$ but not in $A$ as it is not a Nash equilibrium. The only Nash equilibrium is $(00,00)$.